# How to check if the user has an active subscription in Android, Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have an app with a subscription in Google Play.
When the user starts the app, I need to know if the user has an active subscription. This would seem an obvious thing to do, but from searching and trying to implement it, it seems impossible?

I am using Google's newer billing 2/3, following Google's tutorials,

```
class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener
...
public void checkAsync() {
    Log.e(TAG, "checkAsync");
    billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<PurchaseHistoryRecord> list) {
            Log.e(TAG, "checkCached result: " + list);
            if (list == null) {
                return;
            }

            for (PurchaseHistoryRecord ps : list) {
                //System.out.println("PAYMENT: " + ps.getSku() + " : " + ps.getPurchaseTime());
            }
        }
    });
}

public void checkCached() {
    Log.e(TAG, "checkCached");
    List<Purchase> result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).getPurchasesList();
    Log.e(TAG, "checkCached result: " + result);
    if (result == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (Purchase purchase : result) {
        handlePurchase(purchase);
    }
}
```

This is how I think you're supposed to get a user's purchases. But it does not work at all, both calls return null always. It only returns the correct purchases when you reinstall the app or clear the data.

So how exactly is an app supposed to do this?

Purchasing works for the app once I enter internal testing, and download it through the Google Play link. (before that subscriptions do not work at all).

*** updated
So to further clarify:

I am using a valid test user, and subscriptions are working correctly. My question is on the what the API queryPurchases() or queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() are suppose to do.

What I am seeing, is that these only return purchases that have not be processed by the app. They seem to store that the purchase was processed in the apps data.
After the purchase these return null, after the app restarts these return null.
If I clear the app datam or reinstall the app then they return the purchase (once), then again null after restart.

From what I see, these are only useful to detect when a user reinstalls your app, or installs on a different phone. They cannot be used to determine the status of a subscription.

So my question is,

1 - is this something that just does not work in internal testing and will magically work differently when the app is release?

2 - is there a different API that your suppose to use to check the status of a subscription?

3 - are you suppose to manage subscriptions yourself in your app by storing a user preference/cookie when you acknowledge the subscription the first time so you know when the subscription expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, figured it out, was my mistake.

I was calling queryPurchases() in my main activity onCreate(), but the BillingClient was not ready yet.

I moved it to onBillingSetupFinished() and it now returns the correct purchases.
Everything is now working as expected. You get the active subscriptions when you call queryPurchases() after an app restart.

Comment: I'd still be very careful when using `queryPurchases`. Many people report that it does not behave like one would think, cache is not refreshed under any circumstances for some users. Also it's reasonable to expect that `queryPurchases` and `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` return similar data under normal conditions but people are implying they contain/don't contain certain states of SKU, like subscribe -> cancel -> resume

Answer (score 2):

You need "licenced testers". They would allow you to "sideload" your app on devices, even for debug builds. My interpretation of sideload in this case would cover installing from Android Studio build tools as well as `adb install ....` and other methods that don't involve the play store.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

> Ordinarily, the Google Play Billing API is blocked for apps that aren't signed and uploaded to Google Play. License testers can bypass this check, meaning you can sideload apps for testing, even for apps using debug builds with debug signatures without the need to upload to the new version of your app. Note that the package name must match that of the app that is configured for Google Play, and the Google account must be a license tester for the Google Play Console account.

I also don't see how you're using `startConnection`. Until that's completed successfully I wouldn't be sure you have the latest data. I wouldn't be surprised if that makes you get stale values. I would check that carefully to make sure there's no silent errors happening, by both looking at `onBillingSetupFinished` and `onBillingServiceDisconnected`. And for the time being avoid trusting `queryPurchases()`:

https://medium.com/@NandagopalR/integrating-google-play-billing-into-an-android-application-b6eb6af176a7

> The queryPurchases() method uses a cache of the Google Play Store app without initiating a network request. If you need to check the most recent purchase made by the user for each product ID, you can use queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(), passing the purchase type and a PurchaseHistoryResponseListener to handle the query result.

By the way what's the value of `isReady()` right before `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`, and what's the value of `BillingResult::getDebugMessage` and `BillingResult::getResponseCode`?

Also, use `isFeatureSupported`, though it seems it's not like your problem is coming from here. But I'd advise not testing with subscriptions until you get all the moving parts working: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#isFeatureSupported(java.lang.String)

Comment: I am testing it with licenced testers, and subscriptions are working as I said. The issue is queryPurchases() and queryPurchaseHistoryAsync() return null, even after the purchase. It seems these are suppose to return null if the purchase has been processed by the device?? They only return the subscription if I clear the app data/reinstall, so they must be caching that the subscription was processed.

Comment: I think queryPurchaseHistoryAsync is not working as expected, but since there are so many moving parts it's hard to figure out what's wrong without running your code. See if you can get the values for `getDebugMessage` and `getResponseCode`. I also wouldn't rule out disconnecting and calling `startConnection` again, as well as verifying that you have the same behavior with non-subscription purchases. Also interesting to know if you have tried that on 2 different phones from diff manufacturers, or an emulator. Too many potential points of failure.

Comment: After reading a bit more, sounds like billing API is inherently broken on slightly more complicated cases. So even if you get it to work on the simple cases you may need a server to track SKU state or make a REST call through OAUTH2 to billing api to get the proper status of an SKU after cancelling/renewing/etc: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73982566 https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/122.

Comment: this is not a complicated case, this is a very basic case of the user restarting the app. I updated the question, please reply with 1/2/3 as the correct answer.

Comment: You we right, onBillingSetupFinished() had not been called yet.